How to increase row height if created Excel file contains images
Excel file with pictures is created in ASP.NET MVC controller using code from ClosedXML add image and from How to get typed data from sql select statement to Excel:
public async Task<IActionResult> RawData() 
{
    using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    using IDataReader dr = ExecuteReader("select * from foo", out IDbConnection _);

    int currentRow= 1 ;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < dr.FieldCount; j++)
            if (dr.GetFieldType(j) != typeof(byte[]))
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1).Value = dr.GetValue(j).ToString();

else
        {
          long size = dr.GetBytes(j, 0, null, 0, 0);
          byte[] values = new byte[size];
          dr.GetBytes(j, 0, values, 0, values.Length);
          worksheet.AddPicture(new MemoryStream(values)).MoveTo(worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1));
}
        currentRow++;
    }

    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
    var content = stream.ToArray();

    return File(content, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");
}

Bigger images overlap:

How to increase row height if image height is bigger like:

Tried to decrease height using Scale:
  worksheet.AddPicture(new MemoryStream(values)).MoveTo(worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1)).Scale(0.1);

In this case small images are very small and large images still overlap.
